# I just can't get App Check to work on my iOS deployment

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-app-check

I have been trying and trying to enable App Check for the iOS version of my app. The Android version is working fine.

I have followed the instructions at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check

Here is my build output:

```
flutter build ipa                                                      

 Building with sound null safety 

Archiving [bundle ID]...
Updating project for Xcode compatibility.
Upgrading Runner.xcscheme
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: [team ID]
Running pod install...                                             10.6s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        10.8s
Xcode archive done.                                         358.4s
Built .../build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive.
Building App Store IPA...                                           4.2s
Encountered error while creating the IPA:
error: exportArchive: "Runner.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications and App Attest features.


Try distributing the app in Xcode: "open .../build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive"
```

My provisioning profile looks like:

[image]

My XCode Signing & Capabilities:

[image]

I used Xcode to distribute the app archive to App Store Connect, which was successful.

When my son loads the app via TestFlight on his iPhone, he cannot use any function that reads/writes to Firebase (in enforcement mode). I can see in the Firebase console that the requests from his iPhone are invalid and are being rejected.

Anyone got any suggestions? I feel like I've tried everything.

Thanks,

Luke

Comment: Did you check this [flutter fire doc here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/app-check/overview)?

Comment: Hi Chance, that page says "This page is archived and might not reflect the latest version of the FlutterFire plugins. You can find the latest information on firebase.google.com:" and then links to the latest page which I followed. Thanks for yourresponse anyway

Comment: Are you using App Attest or DeviceCheck? I found that by enabling DeviceCheck I got this to work with TestFlight

Comment: Hi @digitalagent, thank you for sharing your experience. At the moment I have both App Attest and DeviceCheck enabled in the Firebase Console. I cannot see a way to disable App Attest. How does your App Attest look in Firebase Console? Or did you just not include any App Attest capability/config on the App side?

Comment: @Luke, I just have both DeviceCheck and App Attest enabled, no special configuration on the App side. I followed the instructions from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/devicecheck-provider?authuser=0&hl=en

Comment: Thanks @digitalagent. I have now checked to ensure that my configuration is as per the instructions. One more question, were you testing the app through TestFlight, or on a fully deployed app?

Comment: Tested through TestFlight initially and it’s also working on a fully deployed app